# Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I use Visual Studio 2017 and create a new ASP.NET Core project.
I add migration for Entity Framework Core as below

```
add-migration "Initial Create"
```

and get the following error:

```
Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework 6.
Build Failed.
```

Do you know how to resolve this error?

---

### **UPDATE 1 - March 14, 2017 - Result received after running command**

```
PM> dotnet ef migrations add "Initial Create"
```

**I see the following output with error message at the end.**

```
Welcome to .NET Core!
---------------------
Learn more about .NET Core @ https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs. Use dotnet --help to see available commands or go to https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs.

Telemetry
--------------
The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to improve your experience. The data is anonymous and does not include command-line arguments. The
 data is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community.
You can opt out of telemetry by setting a DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to 1 using your favorite shell.
You can read more about .NET Core tools telemetry @ https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry.

Configuring...
-------------------
A command is running to initially populate your local package cache, to improve restore speed and enable offline access. This command will take up
 to a minute to complete and will only happen once.
Decompressing 0%Decompressing 1%Decompressing 2%Decompressing 3%Decompressing 4%
Decompressing 5%Decompressing 6%Decompressing 7%Decompressing 8%Deco
mpressing 9%Decompressing 10%Decompressing 11%Decompressing 12%Decompressing 13
%Decompressing 14%Decompressing 15%Decompressing 16%Decompressing 17%
Decompressing 18%Decompressing 19%Decompressing 20%Decompressing 21%De
compressing 22%Decompressing 23%Decompressing 24%Decompressing 25%Decompressin
g 26%Decompressing 27%Decompressing 28%Decompressing 29%Decompressing 30%
Decompressing 31%Decompressing 32%Decompressing 33%Decompressing 34%
Decompressing 35%Decompressing 36%Decompressing 37%Decompressing 38%Decompre
ssing 39%Decompressing 40%Decompressing 41%Decompressing 42%Decompressing 43%
Decompressing 44%Decompressing 45%Decompressing 46%Decompressing 47%
Decompressing 48%Decompressing 49%Decompressing 50%Decompressing 51%Deco
mpressing 52%Decompressing 53%Decompressing 54%Decompressing 55%Decompressing 
56%Decompressing 57%Decompressing 58%Decompressing 59%Decompressing 60%
Decompressing 61%Decompressing 62%Decompressing 63%Decompressing 64%
Decompressing 65%Decompressing 66%Decompressing 67%Decompressing 68%Decompress
ing 69%Decompressing 70%Decompressing 71%Decompressing 72%Decompressing 73%
Decompressing 74%Decompressing 75%Decompressing 76%Decompressing 77%
Decompressing 78%Decompressing 79%Decompressing 80%Decompressing 81%Decomp
ressing 82%Decompressing 83%Decompressing 84%Decompressing 85%Decompressing 86
%Decompressing 87%Decompressing 88%Decompressing 89%Decompressing 90%
Decompressing 91%Decompressing 92%Decompressing 93%Decompressing 94%De
compressing 95%Decompressing 96%Decompressing 97%Decompressing 98%Decompressin
g 99%Decompressing 100% 5083 ms
Expanding 0%Expanding 1%Expanding 2%Expanding 3%Expanding 4%Expanding 5%Ex
panding 6%Expanding 7%Expanding 8%Expanding 9%Expanding 10%Expanding 11%
Expanding 12%Expanding 13%Expanding 14%Expanding 15%Expanding 16%Expanding 17%
Expanding 18%Expanding 19%Expanding 20%Expanding 21%Expanding 22%Expand
ing 23%Expanding 24%Expanding 25%Expanding 26%Expanding 27%Expanding 28%
Expanding 29%Expanding 30%Expanding 31%Expanding 32%Expanding 33%Expanding 34
%Expanding 35%Expanding 36%Expanding 37%Expanding 38%Expanding 39%Ex
panding 40%Expanding 41%Expanding 42%Expanding 43%Expanding 44%Expanding 45%
Expanding 46%Expanding 47%Expanding 48%Expanding 49%Expanding 50%Expandin
g 51%Expanding 52%Expanding 53%Expanding 54%Expanding 55%Expanding 56%
Expanding 57%Expanding 58%Expanding 59%Expanding 60%Expanding 61%Expanding 62%
Expanding 63%Expanding 64%Expanding 65%Expanding 66%Expanding 67%Expa
nding 68%Expanding 69%Expanding 70%Expanding 71%Expanding 72%Expanding 73%
Expanding 74%Expanding 75%Expanding 76%Expanding 77%Expanding 78%Expanding 
79%Expanding 80%Expanding 81%Expanding 82%Expanding 83%Expanding 84%
Expanding 85%Expanding 86%Expanding 87%Expanding 88%Expanding 89%Expanding 90%
Expanding 91%Expanding 92%Expanding 93%Expanding 94%Expanding 95%Expand
ing 96%Expanding 97%Expanding 98%Expanding 99%Expanding 100% 13884 ms


dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet ef migrations add "Initial Create"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (No executable f...and "dotnet-ef":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

---

### **UPDATE 2 - March 14, 2017 - Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using OdeToFood.Services;
using OdeToFood.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace OdeToFood
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // TN - Read setting files
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddSingleton<IGreeter, Greeter>();
            services.AddScoped<IRestaurantData, SqlRestaurantData>(); // TN - One instance of this service for each HTTP request.
            services.AddDbContext<OdeToFoodDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<OdeToFoodDbContext>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                //app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
                //app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions { ExceptionHandlingPath="/error" });

                app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
                {
                    ExceptionHandler = context => context.Response.WriteAsync("Opps!")
                });
            }

            //app.UseDefaultFiles();// TN - will pick index.html
            //app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseFileServer(); // TN - This will include UseDefaultFiles() and UseStaticFiles

            /*
            app.UseWelcomePage(new WelcomePageOptions
            {
                Path = "/welcome"
            });

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                // TN - Read directly from configuration file
                //var message = Configuration["Greeting"];

                // TN - Dependency Injection - Read from configuration string via IOC
                var message = greeter.GetGreeting();
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(message);
            });
            */


            app.UseIdentity();

            //app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);

            // TN - if no route matches
            app.Run(ctx => ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Not found."));
        }

        private void ConfigureRoutes(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
        {
            //Home/Index
            routeBuilder.MapRoute("Default",
                "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 3 - March 14, 2017 - Added csproj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--<Content Include="wwwroot\index.html" />-->
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Controllers\" />
    <Folder Include="Data\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Home\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\images\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: The first error you posted (about EF6 installed) is not an error. It is just a warning. EFCore migration should be added successfully from that command. Are facing any issues other than warning?

Comment: I received a "Build Failed." message after that warning.

Comment: When EF Core executes any commands, first it builds the project. The error message indicates that project couldn't be build. Try building project in Visual Studio and look into Error List window to see what are the build errors. This failure has nothing to do with EF in specific.

Answer (score 46):

**How I resolve this in VS 2017|2019**

- Remove EntityFramework (not EntityFrameworkCore) references from all projects in the solution
- Open the solution folder in Explorer (Windows Explorer)
- Close VS
- delete [image: .vs] folder
- Open the solution again
- Run `update-database` and the alert is gone

**You cannot see '.vs' folder?**

[image]

Comment: Deletion of `.vs`folder is mandatory. Maybe I tested adding some none core packages at some point, but I removed them. Then, not seeing the packages, I though I was OK. but no. Deleting `.vs` folder fixed it!

Answer (score 14):

For those using the new port of [Entity Framework 6.3 and later to .Net Core](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/05/13/ef-preview.aspx), there is a good chance that a solution will include both EfCore and Ef6 artifacts.

e.g. I had migrated an older EF6 repository from .Net Framework to Core, but wanted to make use of the out-of-the-box [AspNet Identity Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1) subsystem, which uses EfCore.

Invariably, during migrations, I would aribtrarily receive errors like:

> Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework6\Update-Database' for Entity Framework 6.

or

> Both Entity Framework 6 and Entity Framework Core are installed. The Entity Framework 6 tools are running. Use 'EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework Core

The solution is simple - when running migration commands, as per the warning, always qualify the commands with the fully qualified:

```
EntityFramework6\Add-Migration Foo
EntityFramework6\Update-Database
```

or

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration Foo
EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database
```

Note that for EF6 fans, at time of writing, the migration tools port to Core isn't quite up to scratch yet, as per [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/05/13/ef-preview.aspx).

Similarly, if you have multiple DbContexts even in the same framework version (EfCore vs Ef6 on Core), you'll need to specify the name of the specific DbContext that you are trying to target, e.g.

```
EntityFramework6\Add-Migration Foo -Context BarDbContext
EntityFramework6\Add-Migration Baz -Context FooDbContext
```

Comment: I believe you're correct although in my situation Visual Studio gives me a cryptic error about the `-Context` parameter not existing if I _do not_ qualify the commands with EF6/EF Core and only shows the highlighted warning if I _do_ qualify the commands, which confused me

Comment: if EntityFramework6\Add-Migration is used, we need to add the old parameters  EntityFramework6\Add-Migration -Force -ProjectName -StartUpProjectName -ConfigurationTypeName
-ConnectionStringName -IgnoreChanges -AppDomainBaseDirectory

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you have at least two projects in your solution each one using either version of EF. By issuing "**Manage NuGet packages for solution...**" you can verify if this is the case. Then, maybe you'd need to sacrifice the one using EF 6.x. After that you'll need to restart VS, maybe some caching prevents removing the package completely when you uninstall it.

**EDIT**: .. or you may live well with both of them, but read carefully the message and follow what it says...

Comment: This was all that was required for me.  The trick in my case was that I did not restart visual studio after removing EF6 from the few projects that had it in my Solution.  Even though no more projects had EF6, and only had EFCore, I was still getting the message.  A restart of Visual Studio made it go away.

Comment: Same for me. Restarting VS fixed it.

Comment: @Alexander_Christov Please elaborate your answer. This answer is not so clear.

Answer (score 4):

If both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed, and you wanna use The Entity Framework 6.
Use this command in the Package Manager Console:

```
'EntityFramework\Update-Database'.
```

No needs to delete or change anything. Just add **EntityFramework** before your EF6 Commands.

Comment: as of January 2023 EF6 is no longer being developed, so EF Core is recommended for new projects. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/)

Answer (score 2):

To add a migration for EF7 use the dotnet command: `dotnet ef migrations add Initial`
To update your database use the dotnet command: `dotnet ef database update`

Comment: Thanks Agua, I've updated my question with the result of "dotnet ef migrations add Initial" command. Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: do you try to add a migration from a class library ?

Comment: No, I add the migration from a new Asp.net Core Web application.

Comment: Can you post your Startup.cs ?

Comment: And do find <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" /> in your csproj ?

Comment: I've added Startup.cs to my question. I've added your seeting in my csproj but it still fails. I use Entity Framework Core in my project so I'm not sure if EF 7 command will resolve this issue. I realize that I have added this ASP.NET Core  Web application in an existing solution which already has several ASP.NET MVC 4 applications and it confuses the Package Manager console. I've created a brand new solution and add a new ASP.NET Core Web application to this new solution and I could run the **add-migration "Initial Create"** successfully.

Comment: how did you add the ef 7 tool in your csproj ? the dotnet command should work

Comment: I've added the content of csproj file in Update 3.

Answer (score 1):

Just...

Edit your project (Project -> right button -> edit) and DELETE EntityFramewok Line

DELETE a line like

```
    <PackageReference Include="Entityframework" Version="6.2.0" />
```

And use ONLY EntityFramework Core

Answer (score 1):

I fixed like this right now:

1. Open: **Visual Studio** > **Package Manager Console**
2. Run this command: **Remove-Module EntityFramework6**